# Mysql automatically adds microseconds to datetime column

Tags: mysql

I am manually adding 2021-02-23 07:23:15 into a datetime column, but it automatically changes it to 2021-02-23 07:23:15.000000

Comment: Those are just two different ways of writing the same moment in time. What is the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: You should not take care about the format sql is storing a date time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the column definition. If it was defined as `DATETIME` it should not include fractional seconds; if it was defined as `DATETIME(6)` it will.

For example:

```
create table t (a datetime, b datetime(6));
                                       
insert into t (a, b) values
  ('2021-01-02 12:34:56.789', '2021-01-02 12:34:56.789');

select * from t;
```

Result:

```
a                    b                          
-------------------  -------------------------- 
2021-01-02 12:34:57  2021-01-02 12:34:56.789000
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vSbUMTBSEyXeyPTiUFjr17/0).